# Java - How to fetch blob storage table data to local console or file using java

Tags: java, blob, azure-blob-storage

Java - How to fetch blob storage table data to local console or file using java
Lets say there is atable on blob storage i.e "Users"
I want all users table data to fetch using java

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy to google it. For example

https://stevedaskam.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/using-jpa-to-insert-and-retrieve-blobs-and-clobs/.

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java

In the first approximation, you need to use JPA and Hibernate (for example, of course) and @javax.persistence.Lob. If your problem is more concrete, tell it more specifically..